# SQLite database error when database is replaced

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have and android application with an SQLite database. When I need to update my database I load all my information that I need to save to local variables, delete te installed database, copy the new one, and store the content of my variables back to the new database. My problem is that after copying the information back to the new database my applications crashes. But if I start my app again with the new database already copied the application starts normally with no problem and all my information is in the application. This is my log cat:

```
    05-17 15:11:16.563 4238-4652/? I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED, mPermissionType:0
05-17 15:11:16.565 4238-4652/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=5180 BSSID=24:a2:e1:eb:18:c3 RSSI=-65 "InoveOnline_5Ghz"WPA_PSK
05-17 15:11:16.823 4238-4652/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=5180 BSSID=24:a2:e1:eb:18:c3 RSSI=-65 "InoveOnline_5Ghz"WPA_PSK
05-17 15:11:17.267 21634-21726/com.aquarismo I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
05-17 15:11:17.272 21634-21726/com.aquarismo E/SQLiteLog: (1032) 
05-17 15:11:17.279 21634-21726/com.aquarismo E/UncaughtException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (Sqlite code 1032), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1507)
        at bbi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673022@12.6.73 (040308-194189626):87)
        at bbz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673022@12.6.73 (040308-194189626):30)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
05-17 15:11:17.302 21634-21661/com.aquarismo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:9 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:213
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 213
05-17 15:11:17.519 21634-21725/com.aquarismo E/SQLiteLog: (1032) 
05-17 15:11:17.521 21634-21725/com.aquarismo E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ts=1526566277482 fatal=1 payload=[B@56ab04 size=1370
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (Sqlite code 1032), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1507)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1372)
        at bbx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673022@12.6.73 (040308-194189626):45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
05-17 15:11:17.540 21634-21727/com.aquarismo I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
05-17 15:11:17.546 21634-21727/com.aquarismo E/SQLiteLog: (1032) 
05-17 15:11:17.549 21634-21727/com.aquarismo E/UncaughtException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (Sqlite code 1032), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1507)
        at bbi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673022@12.6.73 (040308-194189626):87)
        at bbz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12673022@12.6.73 (040308-194189626):30)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

My code to save my data and delete my old database:

```
String destDir = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
String destPath = destDir + "AquaInfo37";
File f = new File(destPath);

// se nao existir cria DB
if (!f.exists()) {
    File directory = new File(destDir);
    directory.mkdirs();
    // apaga todos os ficheiros (BD antigas) que possam existir na
    // diretoria se existir alguma bd, guarda os favoritos. Nome da Bd
    // antiga, se existir, esta em nome[0]
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        String[] array = directory.list();
        // guarda os favoritos da base de dados anterior
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String nome = array[i];
            if (nome.contains("AquaInfo") && nome.length() < 11) {
                // here I save my data to my variables saveRestoreDadosBaseDadosTemporario.getMeusDadosBaseDados(this, nome);
                new_db = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // apaga todas as bd antigas que possam existir
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            new File(directory, array[i]).delete();
        }
    }
    // volta a criar a directoria
    directory.mkdirs();
    // copia para a BD para a nova directoria
    try {
        CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("aquarismo"), new FileOutputStream(destPath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Post the  code.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: So, where exactly in your code does the error occur?

Comment: That is o good question. I couldn't figure out where the problem is. what I believe that is causing the problem is that after creating the new database some variable is still connected to the old database. And when I use that variable it can't finde the database, but i'm not shore.

Comment: Did you read the stacktrace? It says `attempt to write a readonly database` right there...

Comment: Yes I read, but I can't find out why this is happening, I thought that some one could have the same problem and found out what was causing this problem.

Comment: From your description i.e. that the copy works, the issue is probably after the above code has been called. What code is invoked next?